# How to remove $this from eval scope?

Tags: php, eval

I am writing simple template engine and stack with problem: `$this` falls into eval scope even after unseting.

```
class foo
    {

    public function method()
        {
        $code = 'var_dump(isset($this));';
        unset($this);
        var_dump(isset($this)); // produce: boolean false
        eval($code); // produce: boolean true
        }

    }

$foo = new foo;
$foo ->method();
```

How to avoid this without modification `$code` value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to create [unbound](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) [`closure`](http://php.net/closure), where `$this` can not be accessed or might be replaced.

***NOTE:***

1. [`Closure`](http://php.net/closure)s are availible since PHP 5.3.0, as @**invisal** mentioned.
2. [`Closure::bindTo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) availible since PHP 5.4.0.
3. [`Anonymous functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in PHP 5.3.0 should not inherit `$this` from execution context. It was enabled since PHP 5.4.0. Just remove `$evUl = $evUl->bindTo(null);` from example below for PHP 5.3.0 and it will work as expected.

*Example:*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

class foo {
    public function method() {
        $code = 'var_dump(isset($this));';

        $evUl = function()use($code){ eval($code); };
        $evUl = $evUl->bindTo(null);
        $evUl();
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
$foo->method();
?>
```

Shows:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: +1, for using closure. Noted that it only works with PHP 5.3.0+

Comment: I very like this functional way. Just notice: `Closure` appears in 5.3.*, but `bidnTo` appears only in 5.4.*.

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: @sectus, for 5.3.0 just remove `bindTo` line. `$this` not exists in anonymous function context as I mentioned above. Thanks though. Useful link.

Comment: @CORRUPT, i know. Do not worry. :^ )

Answer (score 2):

`$this` can be unset as you have described.

Zend_Framework 1.x has an instance where they do this in `Zend_Service_WindowsAzure_Storage_Batch` class

Note this will not unset the instance, only the reference to the instance within the function scope.

Despite documentation this has been the observed behavior since php 5.1.6.

My only guess on why this won't work with an eval is that it must create a new execution context in which $this is restored into the current scope. This sample exhibits the behavior.

```
class A {
        public function test(){
                print "Before Unset\n";
                print_r($this);
                unset($this);
                print "After Unset\n";
                print_r($this);
                print "Evaled\n";
                eval("print_r(\$this);");
                print "After Eval\n";
                print_r($this);
        }
}
$a = new A();
$a->test();
```

The Output of which is:

```
Before Unset
A Object
(
)
After Unset
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: this in /home/cgray/q.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/cgray/q.php:0
PHP   2. A->test() /home/cgray/q.php:17
Evaled
A Object
(
)
After Eval
A Object
(
)
```

One way that you can dodge this issue is to unset `$this` in the evaluated context.

```
class foo
    {

    public function method()
        {
        $code = 'var_dump(isset($this));';
        unset($this);
        var_dump(isset($this)); 
        eval("unset(\$this);".$code); 
        }

$foo = new foo;
$foo->method();
```

**UPDATE**

It appears as though `include`ing a file within the function scope will also restore `$this`

Comment: +1 for notice, that `$this` will restore itself after `eval()`.

Comment: @CORRUPT Also $this will be restored if you include a file even if the file makes no mention of $this

Comment: Well, `include` acts like a function, but it is not `o_O`. They are both inheriting current context variables. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is a pseudo-variable, it cannot be unset.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: I meant YOU cannot unset it. Of course PHP does not set it when not in an object.

Comment: I am not trying to remove object, i am trying to remove variable `$this` from local scope in `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like `unset($this)` will only work within the function scope. I have confirmed with the test.

```
class foo
{
    public function method()
    {
        unset($this);
        var_dump(isset($this));
    }

    public function method2() {
        var_dump(isset($this));
    }
}
```

The `$code` running within function eval does not run within the function `method`. Confirmed with the test of `$code = 'echo __FUNCTION__;'`

Comment: But looks like `eval()` inherit all variables of current execution scope (`$this` included). Good note, though.